# How do I represent audio file in a format that can be saved in dataset and then can be used in modelling?

Tags: machine-learning, python, deep-learning, tensorflow, dataset

i used the following code to read my audio file

```
from scipy.io import wavfile
samplerate, data = wavfile.read("the path of my audio")
```

but when i tried to save values of data which i get from this code, i found that the length of data variable was 1323000, and it is impossible to represent audio file in (csv)dataset as 1323000 columns for each audio file

so how do I represent my audio file to save it in csv file,i would be grateful if any one teach me !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we can use Audio spectrogram features to represent audio, i use this linkas a guide for
me
[represent audio sound in the data set](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/dali/user-guide/docs/examples/audio_processing/spectrogram.html)